# Almost convex function $\nabla f(y) \geq \alpha \nabla f(x)$.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am interested in maximizing a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ over a convex domain $C$. The function $f$ satisfies the following property:

$$ \alpha \cdot \nabla f(x) \leq  \nabla f(y),$$

where $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ is a positive constant and $x \leq y$ coordinate-wise. It is easy to see that if $\alpha = 1$ the function is convex. The converse is also true.

Are there results that look at the previous definition and show how well one can optimize the function depending on the constant $\alpha$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should $\alpha \cdot \nabla f(x) \le \nabla f(y)$ be understood coordinate-wise?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I am also interested in finding some results for $n=1$.

Comment: I think that the main benefit of an "almost convex" function, is that you can define a convex relaxation of the function and then optimize that surrogate function. Since your original function is "almost convex", the error between the original function and the relaxation should be small and possible to quantify. At the optimum, they might even coincide

Comment: Yes, I agree. In fact, it is the kind of result I am looking for. For instance, let $x^\ast$ be the point where $f$ reaches its maximum and assume that with some algorithm I am able to recover the optimal solution when $f$ is convex.
Is there a result that shows that when $f$ is almost convex the same algorithm outputs a solution $x$ such that $f(x) \geq \alpha f(x^\ast)$.